# Arduino: how to save memory (human readable to byte)

Tags: memory-management, arduino

To save memory, I want the following:

```
0 = offline
1 = starting up
2 = online
3 = error
```

I want to use STATUS_ONLINE in my code (for readability), but the program has to use as less bits as possible.

How can I declare this in my code (Arduino)?

Comment: What language are you using?  In compiled languages, the human-readable constant is translated back to the number at compile time, and has no impact on the size of the generated code.

Comment: Since my Arduino project, memory management becomes an issue… the language is C / C++. What would be the proper code for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use constants

```
uint8_t STATUS_ONLINE = 2;
```

or

```
char STATUS_ONLINE = 'O';
```

The char 'O' takes one byte as the uint8_t type.

---

or you can use unscoped enum:

```
enum {
  STATUS_OFFLINE,
  STATUS_STARTUP,
  STATUS_ONLINE,
  STATUS_ERROR
};
```

example

```
uint8_t connState = STATUS_OFFLINE;
```

or you can use scoped enum:

```
enum ConnState {
  OFFLINE,
  STARTUP,
  ONLINE,
  ERROR
};
```

then you have to use the values as

```
ConnState connState = ConnState::OFFLINE
```

The enum members have int values starting from 0, so ONLINE has value 2.

You can assign int values to use for enum members:

```
enum {
  STATUS_OFFLINE = 'X',
  STATUS_STARTUP = 'S',
  STATUS_ONLINE = 'O',
  STATUS_ERROR = 'E'
};
```

I have char values in the example, but their ASCII values are used. This allows you to use the values in readable output. This applies to scoped and unscoped enums.

```
  Serial.print((char) connState);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need :-)

Answer (score 0):

you want to save data in eeprom? try this
open serial and try to input 1 digit.

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

int value;
void write_string_EEPROM(byte c) //write status
{
    EEPROM.put(0, c);
}
//===============
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("START");
}
//===============
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
     write_string_EEPROM(Serial.read());
  }
  
  delay(5000);
  value = EEPROM.read(0);

  Serial.print((char)value);
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: OP wants to save space, not save data

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things, like using short integer numbers (like `char` or `unsigned char` in C/C++, or (including `stdint.h` respectively `cstdint`) `int8_t` or `uint8_t`. If trying to save even more memory, consider using [bitfields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) for odd-sized/even smaller integers packed together.

But be careful. Depending on the architecture (I'm not familiar with Arduino's), what you save data-wise can be more than made up in bulkier code. I.e., on SPARC if you use `char` it has to be unpacked out of a 4-byte word, operated and repacked. Much larger code than just using `ìnt`, and slower to boot. Write that a few times, and your win in data size is dwarfed by the code increase, unless you have a truckload of such data. Ask your friendly compiler for assembly code for a small test program, in GCC's case something like `g++ -S tst.cc` (or even `g++ -Os -S tst.cc` to get a more representative code, optimizing for size), look at and try to make sense of the resulting `tst.s`. Play with different sized integers, and compare. Compile to object code (like `g++ -Os -c tst.cc`) and look at the resulting object, e.g. with `objdump -h tst.o` for code size.

Never forget Knuth's dictum, "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". And Bentley's advise (in his ---sadly out of print--- "Writing Efficient Programs"): Write a simple, clean program, check if the performance is enough; only if it isn't, *measure* where the bottlenecks are and tackle them in order. A bummed program is harder to write, much more likely to be buggy, and hard to fix/modify.

Comment: nice answer, but the question is much more trivial. it is use of string literal versus int constant to name the states